# Why have resistors on a signal line

Tags: pcb, digital-logic, pcb-fabrication, open-drain

I'm new to electronics so forgive me if this is an obvious question.

I'm making a small circuit to read out a digimatic caliper. There are many designs only and I'm wondering why some components are there. The digimatic uses open collector signaling. There are 2 output lines and 1 input line. One of the schematics can be found here: http://www.imajeenyus.com/electronics/20140109_digimatic_interface/digimatic_circuit.pdf

What I'm wondering is:

- Why does the `CLOCK` signal which goes to the `SPC_CLOCK` have a resistor and capacitor after the pullup. My MCU has internal pullups. Can I use that instead and save myself 3 components?
- Why does the `SPC_REG` contain a resistor which then connects to the base of the transistor?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R3/C6 and R5/C7 form a low pass filter to remove stray RF etc. Having the pullup on the micro side would not have the same effect as with R2/R4. Sure, you could eliminate these components, but you might find nearby cell phones cause strange readings etc. You should always seek to limit the bandwidth of external signals.

The SPC_REG signal is open collector. I dare say the designer could've used the open collector feature of the micros port pins to do the same. The 10k resistor is needed to limit the base current for the transistor. It wouldn't like 5V being shoved where it only likes 0.7V